# How do I tell Vim to use any/all dictionary files that fit a filepath wildcard glob?

Tags: dictionary, vim, wildcard, glob

I am trying to set the dictionary option (to allow autocompletion of certain words of my choosing) using wildcards in a filename glob, as follows:

`:set dict+=$VIM/dict/dict*.lst`

The hope is that, with this line in the initially sourced .vimrc (or, in my case of Windows 10, _vimrc), I can add different dictionary files to my $VIM/dict directory later, and each new invocation of Vim will use those dictionary files, without me needing to modify my .vimrc settings.
However, an error message says that there is no such file.  When I give a specific filename (as in `:set dict+=$VIM/dict/dict01.lst` ), then it works.
The thing is, I could swear that this used to work.  I had this setting in my .vimrc files since I started using Vim 7.1, and I don't recall any such error message until recently.  Now it shows up on my Linux laptop as well as my Windows 7 and Windows 10 laptops.  I can't remember exactly when this started happening.

Yes, I tried using backslashes (as in `:set dict+=$VIM\dict\dict*.lst` ) in case it was a Windows compatibility issue, but that still doesn't work.  (Also this is happening on my Linux laptop, too, and that doesn't use backslashes for filepaths.)

Am I going senile?  Or is there some other mysterious force going on?

Assuming for now that it is a change in the latest version of Vim, is there some way to specify "use all the dictionary files that fit this glob"?

-- Edited 2021-02-14 06:17:07

I also checked to see if it was due to having more than one file that fits the wildcard glob.  (I thought that if I had more than one file that fit the wildcard, the glob would turn into two filenames, equivalent to saying `dict+=$VIM/dict/dict01.lst dict02.lst` which would not be syntactically valid.)  But it still did not working after removing extra files so that only one file fit my pathname of $VIM/dict/dict*.lst .  (I had previously put another Addendum here happily explaining that this was how I solved my problem, but it turned out to be premature.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must expand wildcards before setting an option. Multiple file names must be separated by commas. For example,

```
let &dictionary = tr(expand("$VIM/dict/dict*.lst"), "\n", ",")
```

If adding a value to a non-empty option, don't forget to add comma too (`let` is more universal than `set`, so it's less forgiving):

```
let &dictionary .= "," . tr(expand(...)...)
```

Comment: Thank you!  This solved my problem.  But any idea why the glob worked before?  Did something change in the newest version of Vim?

Comment: @kwantum No idea. It shouldn't as far as I can tell.